# Plotting the ROC curve for a multiclass problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc, auc

I am trying to apply the idea of `sklearn` [ROC extension to multiclass](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html) to my dataset. My per-class ROC curve looks find of a straight line each, unline the `sklearn`'s example showing curve's fluctuating.

I give an MWE below to show what I mean:

```
# all imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
from sklearn.datasets import  make_classification
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
# dummy dataset
X, y = make_classification(10000, n_classes=5, n_informative=10, weights=[.04, .4, .12, .5, .04])
train, test, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.3, random_state=42)

# random forest model
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(train, ytrain)
yhat = model.predict(test)
```

The following function then plots the ROC curve:

```
def plot_roc_curve(y_test, y_pred):
  
  n_classes = len(np.unique(y_test))
  y_test = label_binarize(y_test, classes=np.arange(n_classes))
  y_pred = label_binarize(y_pred, classes=np.arange(n_classes))

  # Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
  fpr = dict()
  tpr = dict()
  roc_auc = dict()
  for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_pred[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
  
  # Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
  fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), y_pred.ravel())
  roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])

  # First aggregate all false positive rates
  all_fpr = np.unique(np.concatenate([fpr[i] for i in range(n_classes)]))

  # Then interpolate all ROC curves at this points
  mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(all_fpr)
  for i in range(n_classes):
    mean_tpr += np.interp(all_fpr, fpr[i], tpr[i])

  # Finally average it and compute AUC
  mean_tpr /= n_classes

  fpr["macro"] = all_fpr
  tpr["macro"] = mean_tpr
  roc_auc["macro"] = auc(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"])

  # Plot all ROC curves
  #plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
  plt.figure(dpi=600)
  lw = 2
  plt.plot(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"],
    label="micro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})".format(roc_auc["micro"]),
    color="deeppink", linestyle=":", linewidth=4,)

  plt.plot(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"],
    label="macro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})".format(roc_auc["macro"]),
    color="navy", linestyle=":", linewidth=4,)

  colors = cycle(["aqua", "darkorange", "darkgreen", "yellow", "blue"])
  for i, color in zip(range(n_classes), colors):
    plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], color=color, lw=lw,
        label="ROC curve of class {0} (area = {1:0.2f})".format(i, roc_auc[i]),)

  plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], "k--", lw=lw)
  plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
  plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
  plt.xlabel("False Positive Rate")
  plt.ylabel("True Positive Rate")
  plt.title("Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) curve")
  plt.legend()
```

Output:

```
plot_roc_curve(ytest, yhat)
```

[image]

Kind of straight line bending once. I would like to see the model performance at different thresholds, not just one, a figure similar to [sklearn's illustration](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html) for 3-classes shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Point is that you're using `predict()` rather than `predict_proba()`/`decision_function()` to define your `y_hat`. This means - considering that the threshold vector is defined by the number of distinct values in `y_hat` (see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913be6d7e485b792ea36e9268be31ed52d0/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L766) for reference), that you'll have few thresholds per class *only* on which `tpr` and `fpr` are computed (which in turn implies that your curves are evaluated at few points only).
- Indeed, consider what the [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_curve) says to pass to `y_scores` in `roc_curve()`, either prob estimates or decision values. In the example from `sklearn`, decision values are used to compute the scores. Given that you're considering a `RandomForestClassifier()`, considering probability estimates in your `y_hat` should be the way to go.
- What's the point then of *label-binarizing* the output? The standard definition for ROC is in terms of binary classification. To pass to a multiclass problem, you have to convert your problem into binary by using OneVsAll approach, so that you'll have `n_class` number of ROC curves. (Observe, indeed, that as `SVC()` handles multiclass problems in a OvO fashion by default, in the example they had to force to use OvA by applying `OneVsRestClassifier` constructor; with a `RandomForestClassifier` you don't have such problem as that's inherently multiclass, see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multiclass-and-multioutput-algorithms) for reference). In these terms, once you switch to `predict_proba()` you'll see there's no much sense in label binarizing predictions.

  ```
   # all imports
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from itertools import cycle
   from sklearn import svm, datasets
   from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
   from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
   from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
   from sklearn.datasets import  make_classification
   from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
   # dummy dataset
   X, y = make_classification(10000, n_classes=5, n_informative=10, weights=[.04, .4, .12, .5, .04])
   train, test, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.3, random_state=42)

   # random forest model
   model = RandomForestClassifier()
   model.fit(train, ytrain)
   yhat = model.predict_proba(test)

   def plot_roc_curve(y_test, y_pred):
       n_classes = len(np.unique(y_test))
       y_test = label_binarize(y_test, classes=np.arange(n_classes))

       # Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
       fpr = dict()
       tpr = dict()
       roc_auc = dict()
       thresholds = dict()
       for i in range(n_classes):
         fpr[i], tpr[i], thresholds[i] = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_pred[:, i], drop_intermediate=False)
       roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

       # Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
       fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), y_pred.ravel())
       roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])

       # First aggregate all false positive rates
       all_fpr = np.unique(np.concatenate([fpr[i] for i in range(n_classes)]))

       # Then interpolate all ROC curves at this points
       mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(all_fpr)
       for i in range(n_classes):
         mean_tpr += np.interp(all_fpr, fpr[i], tpr[i])

       # Finally average it and compute AUC
       mean_tpr /= n_classes

       fpr["macro"] = all_fpr
       tpr["macro"] = mean_tpr
       roc_auc["macro"] = auc(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"])

       # Plot all ROC curves
       #plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
       plt.figure(dpi=600)
       lw = 2
       plt.plot(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"],
       label="micro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})".format(roc_auc["micro"]),
       color="deeppink", linestyle=":", linewidth=4,)

       plt.plot(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"],
       label="macro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})".format(roc_auc["macro"]),
       color="navy", linestyle=":", linewidth=4,)

       colors = cycle(["aqua", "darkorange", "darkgreen", "yellow", "blue"])
       for i, color in zip(range(n_classes), colors):
         plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], color=color, lw=lw,
         label="ROC curve of class {0} (area = {1:0.2f})".format(i, roc_auc[i]),)

       plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], "k--", lw=lw)
       plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
       plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
       plt.xlabel("False Positive Rate")
       plt.ylabel("True Positive Rate")
       plt.title("Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) curve")
       plt.legend()
  ```

Eventually, consider that `roc_curve()` has also a `drop_intermediate` parameter meant for dropping suboptimal thresholds (it might be useful to know).

Comment: Ah, I see. Many thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update on @amiola answer: I had an issue with non-monotonic classes which lead to very strange fuzzy results. In this case a little modification to the function above will work very well:

```
classes = sorted(list(y_test['label'].unique()))
```

Use this in the label_binarize line:

```
y_test = label_binarize(y_test, classes=classes)
```

And then when you need a range in the function, just use:

```
range(len(classes))
```

Thanks to @dx2-66 for the answer. You can check for more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73485714/11479825).