# How to make multiclass cross-validated ROC curve in SKLEARN?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have the following code that outpus the ROC curve of every iteration from the stratified cross validation:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn import metrics
import scikitplot as skplt
import numpy as np

lr_model3 = LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000, penalty='l2')

y_tests = []
y_probabilities = []

print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)


cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X,y):
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
    lr_model3.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_probas = lr_model3.predict_proba(X_test)
    y_probabilities.append(y_probas);
    y_tests.append(y_test)


for i in range(10):
    skplt.metrics.plot_roc(y_tests[i], y_probabilities[i], title = 'Iteration {} ROC Curve'.format(i+1))
```

It outputs the following:

[image]
[image]

Until the 10th iteration

[image]

However, what I want is to display just one ROC curve that summarizes the 10 ROC curves. Is that possible? This is my attempt I am open to other solutions too.

Answer (score 0):

Imo the issue can be found in the fact that you're constructing `y_tests` and `y_probabilities` as lists. Entering into the [`skplt.metrics.plot_roc` implementation](https://github.com/reiinakano/scikit-plot/blob/2dd3e6a76df77edcbd724c4db25575f70abb57cb/scikitplot/metrics.py#L332) you can see that they are required to be *array-like*.

> y_true : (array-like, shape (n_samples)):
> Ground truth (correct) target values.
>
> y_probas : (array-like, shape (n_samples, n_classes)):
> Prediction probabilities for each class returned by a classifier.

To my knowledge, within `sklearn` (on the other hand I don't know the convention of `scikit-plot`), whenever the documentation states that you can use an *array-like* datatype, this does not preclude the possibility of using a list in place of a np array (eg if *array-like of str* is specified you might use a *list of strings*). On the other side, they are more explicit when an argument is specifically required to be a np array, and they specify *ndarray* type (see [sklearn roc_curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html) for instance).

Given that:

- [`LogisticRegression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) works inherently multiclass in your setting (see settings for parameter `multi_class` and the [User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multiclass-and-multioutput-algorithms))

> multi_class: {‘auto’, ‘ovr’, ‘multinomial’}, default=’auto’
> If the option chosen is ‘ovr’, then a binary problem is fit for each label. For ‘multinomial’ the loss minimised is the multinomial loss fit across the entire probability distribution, even when the data is binary. ‘multinomial’ is unavailable when solver=’liblinear’. ‘auto’ selects ‘ovr’ if the data is binary, or if solver=’liblinear’, and otherwise selects ‘multinomial’.

- both `y_true` and `y_probas` are transformed into np arrays [here](https://github.com/reiinakano/scikit-plot/blob/2dd3e6a76df77edcbd724c4db25575f70abb57cb/scikitplot/metrics.py#L395)
- `.roc_curve()` from `sklearn` is called [here](https://github.com/reiinakano/scikit-plot/blob/2dd3e6a76df77edcbd724c4db25575f70abb57cb/scikitplot/metrics.py#L414)

you'll end up having `y_tests` and `y_probabilities` as *lists of np arrays* (and ultimately *lists of lists* after [this point](https://github.com/reiinakano/scikit-plot/blob/2dd3e6a76df77edcbd724c4db25575f70abb57cb/scikitplot/metrics.py#L395) - second premise above) that are not accepted by `.roc_curve()` from `sklearn`

> y_true: ***ndarray*** of shape (n_samples,)
>
> y_score: ***ndarray*** of shape (n_samples,)

Here's the `y_tests` I got from the iris dataset via your code before passing it to `skplt.metrics.plot_roc`.

```
[array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])]
```

Instead, I was able to solve your issue by imposing them to be np arrays both on `iris` and `digits` datasets, as follows

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
import scikitplot as skplt

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

lr_model3 = LogisticRegression(max_iter=200, penalty='l2')

cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X,y):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    lr_model3.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_probas = lr_model3.predict_proba(X_test)
    y_probabilities = np.array(y_probas)
    y_tests = np.array(y_test)

skplt.metrics.plot_roc(y_tests, y_probabilities)
```

Eventually, here are some hints from a similar `sklearn` example of extension of the roc curve to a multiclass setting:  [Plotting the ROC curve for a multiclass problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70278059/plotting-the-roc-curve-for-a-multiclass-problem/70279497#70279497)