# Can I plot ROC curve for multiclass text classification problem, without using OneVsRestClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-classification, roc, multiclass-classification

I have a pickle file that when loaded returns a trained RandomForest classifier. I want to plot the ROC curve for the classes, but from what I read online, the classifier must be wrapped in scikit learn's OneVsRestClassifier. The problem is that since I already have the trained model I cannot wrap it in it to fit the model again.

So I would like to know if there is some workaround to plot the ROC curve. From my trained model I have y_test, y_proba. I also have x_test values.

- The shape of my y_proba examples is: (6715, 5)

[image]

- The shape of y_test is (6715, 5)

[image]

This is the output of the code @dx2-66 suggested:

[image]

[image]

Comment: May https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70278059/plotting-the-roc-curve-for-a-multiclass-problem/70279497#70279497 help? The `RandomForestClassifier` estimator deals natively with multiclass problems without the need of being wrapped in a `OneVsRestClassifier`.

Comment: technically, your saved model is already following one vs rest. Btw ROC curve makes sense for binary classification, it's not easily interpretable in multiclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `y_test` is single column with class id, and your `y_proba` has as much columns as there are classes (at least that's what you'd usually get from `predict_proba()`.

How about this? It should yield you OvR-style curves:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

classes = range(y_proba.shape[1])

for i in classes:
    fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(label_binarize(y_test, classes=classes)[:,i], y_proba[:,i])
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, alpha=0.7)
    plt.legend(classes)
```

Update: solution for non-monotonic class labels:

```
classes = sorted(list(y_test['label'].unique()))

plt.plot([0, 1], linestyle='--')

for i in range(len(classes)):
    fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(label_binarize(y_test, classes=classes)[:,i], y_proba.values[:,i])
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, alpha=0.7)
    plt.legend(['baseline']+classes) # Fixed the baseline legend
```

Comment: Does this work on the principle of one class vs rest? I get a very strange plot. Not looking as expected.

Comment: Yes, this is one vs rest approach. Would you kindly share a sample of `y_proba` and `y_test`?

Comment: I have added examples to my question.

Comment: So apparently you've got classes labeled up to 7 but two of those aren't present? In this case

classes = [2,3,5,6,7] # or whichever are actually present; for i in range(len(classes)): ...

should work regardless.

Comment: Well, yes, two of the classes I dropped because they had very few examples (less than 50 each) that I could train. But I have added a screen shot of the result I got from your code. It really looks strange to me. And also there is usually a diagonal on the chart over which the results are placed.

Comment: You can add the line with `plt.plot([0, 1], linestyle='--')` before the loop. Does the adjustment from the previous comment help?

Comment: I have shared above the screenshot of the result after the modification. As I said, it looks strange. I have tried to binarize the result before I split the data, but then it is even crazier result. See the second chart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247558/discussion-between-dx2-66-and-yana).

Comment: Probably the classifier's `classes_` attribute would work in place of the sorted list of labels, and would be a little more intrinsic?